# How to gain access to Office Online (cloudstorage) api

Tags: office365, office365-apps

I am new to this forum and apologies if this sounds a naive question.

I have been trying to gain access to the office online cloudstorage API. http://dev.office.com/programs/officecloudstorage
I've enrolled in the Microsoft Partner Network program and have filled up the form on that page but have received no response from MS. Does anyone know if it's available to developers? If yes, what do i need to do?

Thanks,
Felice

Answer (score 0):

That link is for cloud storage providers who want to partner with Microsoft - i.e. you are building something that is similar to Box, Dropbox, Google Drive, etc. and want to integrate it with Office Online.

That may be what you want, but, the more common scenario is you want access to Microsoft's cloud storage (aka OneDrive), you want this: https://dev.onedrive.com/

Comment: Yes, that's what we wanted to do, give users the ability to store office native files on our web app because they use it to store other non-office data as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to call the Microsoft Graph REST API. It is one end point combined so you get the access to different apis under one roof. The best thing that you need only to authenticate once.

More information http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs

Sandbox is here 
https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/

and here https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/